# Python Pandas - Read csv with commented header line

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, openfoam

I want to read and process a csv file with pandas. The file (as seen below) contains multiple header lines which are indicated by a `#` tag. I can import that file easily by using

```py
import pandas as pd

file = "data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\s+",
                   names=["Time", "Cd", "Cs", "Cl", "CmRoll", "CmPitch", "CmYaw", "Cd(f)",
                           "Cd(r)", "Cs(f)", "Cs(r)", "Cl(f)", "Cl(r)"],
                   skiprows=13)
```

However, I have a lot of such files with different header names and I don't want to name them (`Time Cd Cs ...`) manually. Also the number of commented lines is different between each file. So I want to automate that task.

Do I have to use something like regular expression here, before passing the data into a pandas dataframe?

Thanks for any advise.

And yes, the header names are also beginning with an `#`.

**data.csv:**

```
# Force coefficients    
# dragDir               : (9.9735673312816520e-01 7.2660490528994301e-02 0.0000000000000000e+00)
# sideDir               : (0.0000000000000000e+00 0.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000002e+00)
# liftDir               : (-7.2660490528994315e-02 9.9735673312816520e-01 0.0000000000000000e+00)
# rollAxis              : (9.9735673312816520e-01 7.2660490528994301e-02 0.0000000000000000e+00)
# pitchAxis             : (0.0000000000000000e+00 0.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000002e+00)
# yawAxis               : (-7.2660490528994315e-02 9.9735673312816520e-01 0.0000000000000000e+00)
# magUInf               : 4.5000000000000000e+01
# lRef                  : 5.9399999999999997e-01
# Aref                  : 3.5639999999999999e-03
# CofR                  : (1.4999999999999999e-01 0.0000000000000000e+00 0.0000000000000000e+00)
#
# Time                      Cd                          Cs                          Cl                          CmRoll                      CmPitch                     CmYaw                       Cd(f)                       Cd(r)                       Cs(f)                       Cs(r)                       Cl(f)                       Cl(r)                   
5e-06                       1.8990180226147195e+00  1.4919925634649792e-11  2.1950119509976829e+00  -1.1085971520784955e-02 -1.0863798447281650e+00 9.5910040927874810e-03  9.3842303978657482e-01  9.6059498282814471e-01  9.5910041002474442e-03  -9.5910040853275178e-03 1.1126130770676479e-02  2.1838858202270064e+00
1e-05                       2.1428508927716594e+00  1.0045114197556737e-08  2.5051633252700962e+00  -1.2652317494411272e-02 -1.2367567798452046e+00 1.0822379290263353e-02  1.0587731288914184e+00  1.0840777638802410e+00  1.0822384312820453e-02  -1.0822374267706254e-02 1.5824882789843508e-02  2.4893384424802525e+00
...
```

Comment: do your header is always at last position of # lines?

Comment: Actually most of the files - so yesno :) EDIT: Yes they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about extracting the header before you read the file?
We only assume that your header lines start with `#`. Extraction of the header as well as its position in the file is automated. We also ensure that no more lines than necessary are read (except the first data line).

```
with open(file) as f:
    line = f.readline()
    cnt = 0
    while line.startswith('#'):
        prev_line = line
        line = f.readline()
        cnt += 1
        # print(prev_line)

header = prev_line.strip().lstrip('# ').split()

df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\s+",
                   names=header,
                   skiprows=cnt
           )
```

With this, you can also proccess the other header lines. It also gives you the position of the header in the file.

Comment: This works quit well. Thank you. However, since my files are quit big, I will only read the first 50 lines as mentioned by @Manakin

Comment: @Sunsheep, my solution only reads the header lines + the first data line. So if your header is 13 lines you read 14 lines.

Answer (score 4):

This should do, it's easy and efficient, it keeps variables at the minimum and it doesn't require any input aside from the filename.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            header = line
        else:
            break #stop when there are no more #

header = header[1:].strip().split()

data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\s+", comment='#', names=header)
```

You first open the file and **read only the commented line** (it will be fast and memory-efficient). The last valid line will be the final header, which will be cleaned and converted to a list. Finally, you open the file with `pandas.read_csv()` with `comment='#'`, which will skip the commented lines, and `names=header`.

Comment: Works well. Thanks. Similar to Stefans answer. He was a little faster :)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of regex could help. This is not the most beautiful of solutions so feel free to post a better solution.

Let's read the first 50 rows of any file to find the last occurrence of the hash which should be the column name.

- ^ asserts position at start of a line
- `#` matches the character # literally (case sensitive)

Code:

```
import re
n_rows = 50

path_ = 'your_file_location'

with open(path_,'r') as f:
    data = []
    for i in range(n_rows): # read only 50 rows here. 
        for line in f:
            if re.match('^#',line):
                data.append(line)

start_col = max(enumerate(data))[0]


df = pd.read_csv(path_,sep='\s+',skiprows=start_col) # use your actual delimiter.

          #      Time            Cd        Cs        Cl    CmRoll   CmPitch  \
0  0.000005  1.899018  1.491993e-11  2.195012 -0.011086 -1.086380  0.009591   
1  0.000010  2.142851  1.004511e-08  2.505163 -0.012652 -1.236757  0.010822   

      CmYaw     Cd(f)     Cd(r)     Cs(f)     Cs(r)     Cl(f)  Cl(r)  
0  0.938423  0.960595  0.009591 -0.009591  0.011126  2.183886    NaN  
1  1.058773  1.084078  0.010822 -0.010822  0.015825  2.489338    NaN
```

## Edit, handling the `#` in the column name.

We can do this in two steps. We can read in 0 rows but slice the header column.

First read in the file from the header row, but set the `header` argument to `None` so no headers will be set.

We can then set the column headers manually:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_,sep='\s+',skiprows=start_col + 1, header=None)
df.columns = pd.read_csv(path_,sep='\s+',skiprows=start_col,nrows=0).columns[1:]

print(df)

       Time        Cd            Cs        Cl    CmRoll   CmPitch     CmYaw  \
0  0.000005  1.899018  1.491993e-11  2.195012 -0.011086 -1.086380  0.009591   
1  0.000010  2.142851  1.004511e-08  2.505163 -0.012652 -1.236757  0.010822   

      Cd(f)     Cd(r)     Cs(f)     Cs(r)     Cl(f)     Cl(r)  
0  0.938423  0.960595  0.009591 -0.009591  0.011126  2.183886  
1  1.058773  1.084078  0.010822 -0.010822  0.015825  2.489338
```

Comment: This cannot handle the `#` comment tag on the header name line which leads to `NaN` in the last coloumn, because pandas thinks the initial `#` is a header name too. But your solution is a good start for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Sunsheep is your delim actually `'\s+'` ?

Comment: Yes. Your edit works well, but in my opinion Stefans answer is a little more elegand :) However, these files are quit big, so your solution with only reading the first 50 lines is quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it, and to save time without using loops, you can create 2 dataframes for `#` commented rows, and the rest.
From those commented rows take last one - that's your header, and then merge data dataframe and this title using `concat()` also if it's neccesary to assign first row as header you can use  `df.columns=df.iloc[0]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['#test1 : (000000)','#test1 (000000)','#test1 (000000)','#test1 (000000)','#Time (000000)','5e-06','1e-05'],
})
print(df)
   

                A
0  #test1 : (000000)
1    #test1 (000000)
2    #test1 (000000)
3    #test1 (000000)
4     #Time (000000)
5              5e-06
6              1e-05

df_header = df[df.A.str.contains('^#')]
print(df_header)
         

          A
0  #test1 : (000000)
1    #test1 (000000)
2    #test1 (000000)
3    #test1 (000000)
4     #Time (000000)
df_data = df[~df.A.str.contains('^#')]
print(df_data)
       A
5  5e-06
6  1e-05

df = (pd.concat([df_header.iloc[[-1]],df_data])).reset_index(drop=True)
df.A=df.A.str.replace(r'^#',"")



print(df)
          

     A
0  Time (000000)
1          5e-06
2          1e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that comments always start with a single '#' and the header is in the last commented line:

```py
import csv

def read_comments(csv_file):
    for row in csv_file:
        if row[0] == '#':
            yield row.split('#')[1].strip()

def get_last_commented_line(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        decommented_lines = [line for line in csv.reader(read_comments(f))]
        header = decommented_lines[-1]
        skiprows = len(decommented_lines)
        return header, skiprows

header, skiprows = get_last_commented_line(path)
pd.read_csv(path, names=header, skiprows=skiprows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read the lines in file
with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Last commented line is header
header = [line for line in lines if line.startswith('#')][-1]

# Strip line and remove '#' 
header = header[1:].strip().split()

df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\s+", names=header, comment='#')
```